# How to point a public URL to internal (hidden) server with all links following.

Tags: redirect, server

I know that you all will be mad with a simple question like this, but I was unable to find a clear answer, therefore I risk to bother :)
Yes, I have read [Changing_The_Site_URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL), but could not find what I need...

**In simple terms:** I would like to have a wordpress installation on a bitnami server, sitting on my local (linux) machine, which would be linked transparently for the user to the company intranet (personal) website.

**In detail:**
What I have running is a bitnami installation on *http://mymachine:8080/wordpress*. I can place a .htaccess on the intranet website (but not much, e.g. no wordpress itself): say *http://intranet/user*. I would like the user to type in the intranet address (http://intranet/user) and get to the wordpress on mymachine:8080/wordpress.

**Now to the trouble:**

I have set up a HTTP 301 redirection and that works, however, the address in the browser and all the wordpress addresses (RSS,etc) point to the mymachine address. This is not what I want, as I need to be able to replace the local machine and the user should not see any change.

I have tried setting the "WP_HOME"/"WP_SITEURL"  of the wordpress and a making a  301 redirect in the intranet .htaccess, but the site is then either not visible or it still points to the mymachine.

Is there something more I should set up?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting sounds more like a DNS/Apache problem than a WordPress problem.

You would need to set the DNS alias and vhosts on up on apache in your intranet. Doing it via WordPress is not the way to do it, and would involve jumping through hoops and putting a massive amount of effort in for something that runs slow and has problems. The port 8080 is also going to be an issue here.

The only other method that's straightforward is to cloak the page and put a full page iframe leading to your local machine, but it is a hack/kludge, and all the URLs will still show your local machines URL not the pretty URL. It will also be decloaked if the user opens a new tab or window, and you won't be able to copy paste addresses or remember pages between browser sessions

If it worked with WordPress as you desire it to, then I could set up an install, specify apple.com as the site url, and steal all of Apples traffic.